# How to change after postback URL in asp.net 4.5 web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, postback, postbackurl

Here a button that does a postback

```
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnBestPrice"  OnClick="btnSearchBestPrice_Click">Search Best Price</asp:LinkButton>
```

Assume that this button is clicked on page

```
http://localhost:47207/Default?ClusterId=131
```

Now after the postback is completed, the page is still

```
http://localhost:47207/Default?ClusterId=131
```

However, after the postback, i want to make URL to be

```
http://localhost:47207/Default
```

Is that possible?

If i make a redirect, the postback event would be loss. I still want to process the postback event perfectly fine. So if somehow i can set the postback url to be raw url of the page on the client side or?

asp.net 4.5 web forms c#

Comment: Server.Transfer("Default.aspx") ?

Comment: Server.Transfer would render the "Default" page but not change the original URL.  Seems like what you want is Response.Redirect after your post-back processing.

Comment: @Seano666 if i make response.redirect it would cause postback data to be lost am i incorrect?

Comment: Not if you redirect AFTER whatever post-back logic you are referring to.  You don't mention what you are doing on post-back, but you can do anything you normally do such as database calls, etc.  Then, at the end of whatever action you are doing, call a Response.Redirect to your default page.

Comment: @Seano666 postback is a button click which postbacks textbox data

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG What are you then doing with this textbox data?

Comment: @Seano666 i am using it to retrieve data then display to users :)

Comment: So, the user will be on a "settings" page and change some setting. When saved, you want the user re-directed to the home page and shown a home page with the settings applied?

Answer (score 0):

I assume your postback is displaying some information to user, but have to change the URL without interrupt the process.

First of all you have to understand that if you changed the URL in the server side, the browser will treat it as a new page and make a new request. Response.Redirect is basically telling the browser it is time to move onto another page. So you cannot change the URL while remaining in the same request. (while Server.Transfer is remaining at the same URL but different page which is not what you want)

So I have 2 solutions for you, the following one make sense to me but there is still redirecting the page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (Session["ClusterId"] != null) {
        try {
            int ClusterId = int.Parse(Session["ClusterId"]);
            // Code here
        } catch { }
        Session.Remove("ClusterId");
        return;
    }
}

protected void btnSearchBestPrice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int ClusterId = int.Parse(Request["ClusterId"]);
    Session.Add("ClusterId", ClusterId.ToString());
    Response.Redirect("~/Default");
}
```

---

Here is another solution that does all the actions in your btnSearchBestPrice_Click event without Redirect and Session, and bind a JavaScript page ready event, [call history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) and also wipe out the unnecessary parameters in the action attribute of your form element.